# converting a function for d3.csv to work with array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, csv, d3.js

I am new to d3 and this may seem to be a very simple question. I am trying to create a graph, for which I wrote a code that draws a graph with CSV data. But I am now trying to create the same graph with array data.

```
somevariable = d3.csv(ds, function(da) {
  da.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = f.parse(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
  });
 do more functions ()....
});
```

I want to use same functions for creating a graph with an array of objects that I am trying to parse. I am unsure how to parse array data and use it, unlike `d3.csv`. I am also getting an error near d.date parse using the format that t.slice is not a function while it works fine with CSV data. It would be very helpful if someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below example which uses array

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var arrData = [
  ["2016-10-02",200],
  ["2016-10-09", 300], 
  ["2016-10-12", 150]];

// create a new array that follows the format which D3 expects
var data = arrData.map(function(d) {
    return {
      date: parseDate(d[0]),
      value: d[1]
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks for that answer, my arr data contains a key value pair and a year value, which I am trying to parse into %Y format.I am getting an error saying n.getfullYear is not a function.

Comment: Paste the sample data which you are trying to parse

Comment: [{ key : "apple" , date : 1994 , price:100},{key : "orange" , date: 2014 , price:50}, {key: "apple" , date : 2014 , price:175}]

Comment: Since it contains only year, no need to parse it as date and d3 chart expects date in the same format, so no need to convert/parse it